# Suggestions for design approach to React app walkthrough

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, modal-dialog

I'm about to try to create a walkthrough for a [web app](https://mfahelper.netlify.app/) created using React. I'm trying to think of the best way to do it, and have been thinking of using things like Material UI's [modal](https://material-ui.com/components/modal/) component. I'm thinking I should also include some kind of arrow component that points the user to whichever element (button, link, etc) on my page I want them to click next. Also I will want to create a backdrop to fade the screen except for whichever element I want the users attention to be drawn to.

I feel like this must have been done many times before, but I can't find anything from searching. Obviously whenever I Google "react walkthrough/guide/intro" I just get suggestions for teaching basic React.

(NB: I'm not looking to do one of those intro sliders, as I want to provide a more detailed step-by-step)

Comment: There are tools on the web that allow you to do that such as Pendo. If however you want to implement it yourself, you need to maintain a state map. Where you store the current state of user walkthrough. Each state then needs to know what modal/popover needs to open and the target element if there is a popover. However this question is a very broad and not suitable for StackOverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword your need to search for is 'tour'. Searching on google for 'react tour', I found 2 libraries for you:

- React Joyride: https://github.com/gilbarbara/react-joyride | [Live Demo](https://react-joyride.com/)
- reactour: https://github.com/elrumordelaluz/reactour | [Live Demo](https://reactour.js.org/)

Both seem to have similar features:

- Instruction modal that explains about an element on the page.
- The modal is positioned next to the highlighted element.
- The window will scroll down to the highlighted element if it's outside of the viewport.
- The element is highlighted to bring more attention while the rest of the page is in the backdrop.
- There are steppers on the modal to indicate which step you're on.

Comment: That's excellent, thanks! I'll try React Joyride first and see if I can get it working!